# How to check the performance & memory usage of the flash application at run time?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, performance, actionscript

I have a flash application which consist of Grid Components, Button, Label, and Combo-box Components. All these components are used more than 70 times(simultaneously) with in the application. So Its takes too much of memory. So How can I test the memory usage of each component at the time of running. Is there any plug-in available for browsers to find the memory usage.

I'm using flash CS3 and ActionScript 3.0. The application suppose to run in browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I think [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) will help you. Besides memory and FPS monitor, it has lots of other useful features.

You can also try [FlashPreloadProfiler](http://jpauclair.net/FlashPreloadProfiler/) to monitor memory and DisplayObjects lifecycle.

Comment: +1 You have to try MonsterDebugger even if it's just to play their unbelievable tutorial. Yes, I said "play". The tutorial is a game.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Abobe Flash Builder, you can use its built in profiler.

- [Adobe Flash Builder 4 * Profiling Flex applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0169-8000.html)

Comment: +1. That's the best tool available for profiling memory (at least, the best I'm aware of). For profiling performance, though, it's not so great, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple performance stats display, check out [Mr. Doob's Stats class](https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats).

For a more in-depth look into your application's performance, there is [FlashPreloadProfiler](http://jpauclair.net/FlashPreloadProfiler/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this info:
http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/memory/

Memory consumption:

```
import flash.system.System;
function performMemTest(e:Event):void {
    trace(System.totalMemory);
}
```

About Frame Rate you can check by link.